# I am not allowed to pass a string from resource file within a switch case [Android]

Tags: java, android

I have few buttons and I have the following click listener for the same:

```
 private View.OnClickListener onclick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.home:
                    break;
                case R.id.contact:
                    break;
                case R.id.terms:
                    break;
                case R.id.touch:
                    show(R.string.about_us); //Error here
                    break;


            }
        }
    };
```

On each button click I display the same popup, only the text differs. I have text in `strings.xml` file

below is my dialog function:

```
 public void show(String message){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.terms);

        //dialog.setTitle("Terms & Conditions");
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(message);
        text.setTypeface(helv_light);
        ImageButton dialogButton = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        // dialogButton.setTypeface(helv_light);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```

in case `R.id.touch:` My IDE complains with the following message:

show(java.lang.string) cannot be applied to (int).

If I replace `show(R.string.about_us);` with `show(""+R.string.about_us);` The error goes away, what do I miss here?

Comment: If you replace `show(R.string.about_us);` with `show(""+R.string.about_us);`, you'll get the string **id**s (something like **0x7000123** - converted to string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getResources().getString` for getting string from `strings.xml` :

```
show(v.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.about_us));
```

Answer (score 4):

`R.string.about_us` is an int value, is not a string. To keep both you can overload  `show`, providing the integer parameter, and call

```
 public void show(final int messageId) {
    sendMessage(getResources().getString(messageId));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `R.string.*` values are `int`s. You need to use `getResources().getString(R.string.str_id)` to get the actual string value.

Comment: I am using `R.string`